# How to use CNAME to load webapplication

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, domain-name-system, cname-record, vestacp

I've built an application and planning to host it at example.com
I have about 10 customers who want the application to be hosted on their brand name (White labeled).
Instead of deploying the same application 10 times, I would prefer hosting the application at example.com and point the CNAME of each of the customer's domain to example.com

I implemented the same but for some reason, that's not working as expected.

**My Current Setup:**

```
customer1.tld.          60      IN      CNAME   prod.example.com.
prod.example.com.       59      IN      A       62.xx.xxx.204
```

When I hot prod.example.com on a browser, it works seamlessly, however when I enter customer1.tld it's not working. Logic - customer's dns (CNAME) should point to my hostname and my hostname (A record) should point to my server IP.
Anything that I have missed out?

Other Related Information that I'm using:

- VestaCP
- Ubuntu 16.04
- Apache/2.4.29

Answer (score 0):

The web server needs to be aware of all these aliases: list them on the [`ServerAlias` directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#serveralias) of the `<VirtualHost>` of your application.

```
<VirtualHost>
    ServerName prod.example.com
    ServerAlias customer1.example.net customer2.example.org

    . . .
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

CNAMEs are not allowed at the apex of a domain. So you need to do it like this:

```
customer1.tld.          60      IN      A       62.xx.xxx.204
customer2.tld.          60      IN      A       62.xx.xxx.204
prod.example.com.       59      IN      A       62.xx.xxx.204

www.customer1.tld       60      IN      CNAME   prod.example.com.
www.customer2.tld.      60      IN      CNAME   prod.example.com.
```

Some cloud-based DNS services like Route 53 offer a new service called aliases that can be used to get around this problem, as they allow CNAMEs at the apex that way.